# Privacy Options using NodeJS for an Social media app

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I M building a social media app similar to Instagram  and new to NodeJS And Firebase. I want app to have a similar privacy setting to that of Instagram like private profile and public profile. An help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

ref: 
[instagram account settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AGsC.jpg)

Comment: You want to get profile part right?

Comment: yeah, if the user is following it should show posts of that user els  should show this account is private

Comment: I will ask this question to another forum.

Comment: Is it still open? I have the solution